# Springboot Hibernate @ManyToOne Mapping issue, Not sure how to link currently logged in user id to item added by the user

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am having trouble figuring out how to get the currently logged in users id and link it to the item they add using @ManyToOne mapping. When I add the item to database via my front end, id is null. I Know I'm missing some code just not sure what. I am new to using SpringBoot

Here is my code:

I have added the service class, repo class, controller class and the entity below: Please help with this issue and thank you in advance.

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "msItem")
   public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long itemId;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String itemName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int itemPrice;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String itemDesc;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String category;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String image;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private User user;

    public long getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(long itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public int getItemPrice() {
        return itemPrice;
    }

    public void setItemPrice(int itemPrice) {
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
    }

    public String getItemDesc() {
        return itemDesc;
    }

    public void setItemDesc(String itemDesc) {
        this.itemDesc = itemDesc;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public User user() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

  }







   @Service
   public class ItemServiceImp{

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;

    public List<Item> listItems(User user) {
         return itemRepository.findByUser(user);
    }
}







   @Repository
   public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {

    public List<Item> findByUser(User user);
   }







   @Controller
   public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;





    @GetMapping("/listItem")
    public String listing(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("item", new Item());
        return "addItem";


    }

    @PostMapping("/process_Item")
    public String itemAdd(Item item)  {

        itemRepository.save(item);
        return "home_page";


    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can use the annotation `@CreatedBy` and `@LastModifiedBy` on the fields level that should hold the user id information.
Then you need to create a class that implement the `AuditorAware` interface and you get the user id (information) from the security context / principal.
Don't forget to add `@EnableJpaAuditing`